# How to cleanup groupdashboard picklingError

Tags: plone

On a migrated Plone website (3.3 -> 4.0) I just can't apply 'portlets' step.

The traceback:

```
2013-01-23 12:15:51 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1358939751.450.337074106184 http://localhost:8080/plone/portal_quickinstaller/prefs_reinstallProducts
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 135, in publish
  Module Zope2.App.startup, line 291, in commit
  Module transaction._manager, line 93, in commit
  Module transaction._transaction, line 322, in commit
  Module transaction._transaction, line 416, in _commitResources
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 558, in commit
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 606, in _commit
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 640, in _store_objects
  Module ZODB.serialize, line 422, in serialize
  Module ZODB.serialize, line 431, in _dump
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'collective.groupdashboard.interfaces.IGroupDashboardLayer'>: import of module collective.groupdashboard.interfaces failed
```

Do I need to add this addon back to my setup or could I delete this instance without it ? Is there any way to fake this class to then delete it ?

I don't know how I can remove that stuff. Any workaround welcomed !

Comment: The easiest would be to reinstall that add on and remove the portlet entry from your dashboard.